# OnSave event removing field value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a code that fills my subject field in the appointment entity. But When i click on save i see the value in subject field but then it disappers suddenly. Its removing/clearing the field after it fills. How can i fix it ? I think something wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your code is attached to the save event.  Two options:

1. Change your code to run synchronously.  The problem is probably this: the save runs, you send the request, the save is sent to the platform without a subject, the request comes back and populates subject, the save completes and asynchronously refreshes the page with current values (which resets subject to blank)
2. Attach your function to form load instead of form save.

Comment: Synchronous is the solution ! Thanks for explaining the difference.